# How to use Typescript with gulp to generate a single file from multiple files?

Tags: typescript, gulp

So all my typescript issues are gone, yay.

I was converting my code to use typescript so I could split my codes for better readability.

I got, for now, `index.ts`, `utils.ts` and `config.ts`.

Index import utilities function from `utils` and `config`.

Now I noticed that I need to use `umd` to generate a single file usable easily in a browser.

My gulp task:

```
task('compileCore', function () {
  return src('src/assets/test/v1/core/index.ts')
      .pipe(ts({ "outFile": "build/assets/test/v1/core.js" }))
});
```

index.ts

```
import { getRandom } from './utils'
let something: string = "That's my string! "+getRandom()
```

I could use gulp to concatenate all my ts files before compiling but development would be hard.

Error:
`utils.ts(7,1): error TS6131: Cannot compile modules using option 'outFile' unless the '--module' flag is 'amd' or 'system'.`